# RxJava - Combining the results of multiple Singles and return as one

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I've got the following problem:
I have a Single that returns a list of objects, inside each object, there is a field that is also a Single, and that returns a list of items (which is what i need), but i also need this list to be returned as one result, rather than as each individual single..

I have an Observable that i can use which is wrapping all of this code, so i would like to emit the result in onNext.

Additionally, I also need to add the individual results of each Single into a cache, with the key being the parent object

Code:

```
object.getListOfObjects().doOnSuccess { objectList ->
                      objectList.map { singleItemInList ->
                          singleItemInList.listOfValues.subscribe({ valueList ->
                              cache[singleItemInList] = valueList
                              emitter.onNext(valueList)
                            // ^ this is the bit where i need to get all values instead of 
                            //   emitting on next for each item
                          },{
                              emitter.onError(it)
                          })
                      }
                  }.subscribe( {
                   /* no-op*/

                  }, {
                      emitter.onError(it)
                  })
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT - Extra details:

```
fun getListOfObjects(): Single<List<Object>> =
        Single.zip(
            allObjects().map { it.objects() }
        ) { t: Array<Any> ->
            t.map { it as Object }
        }

Object {
    [...]
    val listOfValues: Single<ValueList>
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an approach, but it is far from pretty... Any suggestions as to how this could be implemented more prettily would be greatly appreciated! :D

```
object.getListOfObjects().doOnSuccess { objectList ->
                    val list = objectList.map { singleItemInList ->
                              singleItemInList.listOfValues.subscribe({ valueList ->
                                  cache[singleItemInList] = valueList
                              },{
                                  emitter.onError(it)
                              })
                          }
                      }.flatten().map {
                        it.toObservable()
                      }
                    Observable.zip(list) { itemList ->
                      val compoundList = mutableListOf<Value>()
                      for (i in itemList.indices) {
                        val singleList = itemList[i] as? List<Value>
                        singleList?.map { item ->
                            compoundList.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                    emitter.onNext(compoundList) 
                    // ^ this now emits the entire list instead of 
                    // each sublist individually
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }.subscribe({
                   /* no-op */
                }, {
                   emitter.onError(it)
                })
            }.subscribe({
                /* no-op */
            }, {
               emitter.onError(it)
            })
```

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure the other answer (`.flatMap().toList()`) should have been sufficient to solve the original outlined issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap` operator in that case and at the final step `toList`

```
object.getListOfObjects()
    .flatMap { objectList -> objectList.listOfValues() }
    .toList()
    .subscribe({ result -> TODO() }, { error -> TODO() })
```

Comment: i was trying this out, but im missing a step i think in your solution. In my problem, the `singleItemInList` is the one containing the `listOfValues`, not the `objectList`.. would having an extra flat map in the `singleItemList` work?

Comment: Can you provide signature of your functions and class structure (simplified) for that scenario?

Comment: added more info to the question as requested :)